# Display result on specified column based on computed result

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

I have **2** db tables: Customer's Information and balances

**Customer** : Customer_ID, Name

**Transaction**: Customer_ID, Transaction_Name, Transaction_Amount... *(Other columns but not necessary for my question)*

**Sample expected query output:**

```
Customer_ID | Debit_Balance | Credit_Balance
1           |         500.00|
2           |               | 300.00
```

**Explanation:** Customer 1 has 500.00 remaining balance and Customer 2 has 300.00 extra amount paid *(This is usually (-) negative in nature)*

**Question:**

How to do this in single query alone? I just wanted to generate report *(like the above sample output)* to display the result amount **if** `positive` as Debit_Balance and Credit_Balance for those `negative` balances then will process the result using Php.

**UPDATE:**
I used to do this processing of transaction amounts : I Sum up all the `Transaction_Amount` based on their `Transaction_Name`.

i.e.

> Balance = (All Transaction_Name 'SALES' ) **Less (-)** (All
>   Transaction_Name 'PAYMENT')

*But this will forced me to create dummy table as repository table for my report and more php condition to compare and INSERT.*

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: @juergend I tried Sum(Transaction_Amount) as Debit_Balance, Sum(Transaction_Amount) as Credit_Balance but resulting to 2 columns with values. This is supposed I think to be conditional query if this exist.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like below:

```
SELECT C.customer_id, C.Name, 
IF(SUM(Transaction_Amount)>0, SUM(Transaction_Amount),'') as Debit_Balance,  
IF(SUM(Transaction_Amount)<=0, SUM(Transaction_Amount),'') as Credit_Balance
From Customer As C 
LEFT JOIN Transaction  As T ON C.customer_id = T.customer_id
GROUP BY T.customer_id
```

Comment: Thank you but I ended creating dummy table for extra php processing. The above query would result to duplicate output. e.g. Debit_Balance and Credit_Balance has both values w/c is not I intended to see. I just want value either of the 2 fields not both. :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want a single row of output for each customer, with the balance in either one column or another depending on whether it's positive or negative. Try (if we're using standard SQL):

```
select
  subqry.Customer_ID
, case
    when subqry.Balance >= 0 then subqry.Balance
  end as Debit_Balance
, case
    when subqry.Balance < 0 then subqry.Balance * -1
  end as Credit_Balance
from (
  select
    Customer_ID
  , sum(
      case Transaction_Name
        when 'SALES' then Transaction_Amount
        when 'PAYMENT' then Transaction_Amount * -1
        else null
      end
    ) as Balance
  from Transaction
  group by Customer_ID
) as subqry
```

No need to join with the Customer table so far because we're not using the Customer Name anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I can't come up with anything easier than this:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, pos.amount debit_balance, neg.amount credit_balance
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(t.transaction_amount) amount, t.customer_id
           FROM   transaction t
           WHERE  t.transaction_amount > 0
           GROUP BY t.customer_id) pos ON pos.customer_id = c.customer_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(t2.transaction_amount) amount, t2.customer_id
           FROM   transaction t2
           WHERE  t2.transaction_amount < 0
           GROUP BY t2.customer_id) neg ON neg.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

The first subquery sums up all positive values for each customer, while the second subquery sums up all the negative values. Then you get all customers and combine the two corresponding values into one result.